# Should Angular Elements be used as reusable components across multiple Angular applications?

Tags: angular, angular6, web-performance, angular-elements

We need to reuse components across application in different repos. One solution we have is to provide these components as npm packages. We are considering switching to Angular Elements and wondering if this is the right approach.

Will Angular Elements share the common vendor files or will it be n times the payload for n elements on my page?

Will multiple Angular Elements work seamlessly and not conflict with the parent Angular app or with each other? We have heard about some Zone js conflicts?

If there is shared cached data (eg. in a ngrx/redux store), will the Elements have access to it?

Are there any benefits to using this approach than just creating separate libs and exporting regular components as npm packages?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, each element is completely self-contained, with no code sharing. Angular Elements is really designed to allow standalone components to run in apps created with other architectures. If you need access to redux, etc, you're probably better off creating shared modules.

Comment: @Brandon does isolation also mean that the same vendor files are duplicated across the Angular Elements?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Each "element" contains everything it needs to function.

Comment: This is even more concerning: Using multiple Web Components built from Angular Elements breaks the consuming application. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23732

Comment: In my opinion, Elements is a great idea, but isn't ready for production use yet.I'm hoping they'll make some progress on it soon.

Comment: There are caveats with the current implementation, for sure. 'ready for production' will heavily depend on how you're using these constructs.

Comment: Are any updates on this in Angular 8?